# Java script program

Tags: javascript

I just started and it is really confusing because when I write my code there is no red warning on the eclipse, however when I run the program, it does not work. The question is:

Write a program that displays employee IDs and first and last names of employees. Use a class

Comment: You won't get any help if you don't first share your current approach and ask about specific issues you have with it.

Answer (score -1):

```
function Employee() {
    var id;
    var firstname;
    var lastname;
}

Employee.prototype.display = function() {
    console.log("Employee id = " + this.id + ", firstname = " + 
                 this.firstname + ", lastname = " + this.lastname);                 
 }

var newEmployee = new Employee;

newEmployee.id = 1;
newEmployee.firstname = "John";
newEmployee.lastname = "Doe";

newEmployee.display();
```

Comment: The actual question, which is not very clear, is saying that Eclipse is not working correctly. You just helped with his home assignment.